# Hibernate Joda DateTime Sorting

Tags: hibernate, jodatime, spring-data-jpa

I am using Joda DateTime and the UserType library for hibernate 4

I have a JPA entity with the following field

```
@Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "lastUsedDateTimeStamp"), @Column(name = "lastUsedDateTimeStamp_TMZ") })
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeAsString")
private DateTime lastUsedDateTimeStamp;
```

I am using a normal Spring Data JPA repository as follows:

return repository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 5, new Sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "lastUsedDateTimeStamp"))).getContent();

However when I look at the sql that hibernate throws out in the logs it end as follows:

```
order by
        entity.lastUsedDateTimeStamp,
        entity.lastUsedDateTimeStamp_TMZ asc limit ?
```

This means that the sorting is not working on the lastUsedDateTimeStamp column as expected, as the "asc" keyword is after lastUsedDateTimeStamp_TMZ instead of lastUsedDateTimeStamp.

Does anyone know how I can fix it so that the query specifies "asc" on the correct field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this one myself, 
had to write my own custom PersistentDateTimeAsString and AbstractMultiColumnDateTime classes that reversed the default order of the 2 fields.

timezone is now first in the order and then date time.
So the sql now looks like this:

```
order by
        entity.lastUsedDateTimeStamp_TMZ,
        entity.lastUsedDateTimeStamp asc limit ?
```

Comment: Any chance you could add your custom classes to this answer?

Comment: But this can not work properly, isn't it?
I suppose, the only cross-platform way to solve this is to create a timestamp field. And in Postgres one can make a function, and to sort by its result.

Comment: I'm sorry, but we don't even use this solution anymore. We have moved to Java 8 Time api, which does not require this hack. I would advise the same for any one else now