# Sorting for joda datetimes

Tags: java, spring, sorting, datetime, jodatime

I'm having the same problem as in [Hibernate Joda DateTime Sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14278812/hibernate-joda-datetime-sorting/17278234), I want to sort for a Joda datetime field that consists of two columns, the time and the zone. But I don't get it to work. I don't know how to write the classes `PersistentDateTimeAsString` and `AbstractMultiColumnDateTime`, could someone please give me some lines of code for that?

My Model looks like this:

```
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTimeWithZone")
@Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "created"),
@Column(name = "created_zone") })
private DateTime created;
```

Comment: Well what happens with the code that you've tried?

Comment: I get it in the order of the db!

Comment: Well how exactly are you trying to order it? Show your code - even if it's very similar to the code in the linked post. (This question should stand alone.)

Comment: I've commented to ask [macalase](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14303396/139010) to post their implementations on your behalf, since you don't have sufficient rep to comment yet.

Comment: Joda's DateTime implements Comparable, so I don't really understand the trouble?

Comment: My syntax for ordering is as follows:
`int perPage = 10;
Page<Activity> activities = activityRepository.findAll(QActivity.activity.user.in(users),
    new PageRequest(pageIndex, perPage, new Sort(Direction.ASC, QActivity.activity.created.getMetadata().getExpression().toString())));`

Comment: thanks for asking! Don't know why it does not work!

Comment: The orderby clause looks like this:
`order by
    activity0_.created,
    activity0_.created_zone asc`
For sorting the zone is used and the zone is mostly equal!
Could it be a solution to use another usertype?
Does anyone have an idea?